# How to Get Application pool information on a Web Page

Tags: asp.net, application-pool, pool, nopcommerce

Does anyone know out to output the memory usage of an application pool to a label on webpage? Sadly i don't have access to the server itself so i cannot go on to IIS directly. I'm running nopcommerce and want to find out how much memory it is taking up in the application pool.

Comment: Do you know if other applications are in the pool as well? that could skew your results.

Answer (score 1):

No, there was no other applications running in the app pool. I found the issue. Nopcommerce was running around 110mb idle and the hosting company i was with put the application pool size at 125mb. When in this configuration it was taking about 30 to 40 seconds for each page load.

I was able to get them to increase the pool size to 256mb and the change was instant! Pages load in 3 to 4 seconds now.